# Wi-Fi With some problems

Tags: settings, wifi, software-installation

The problem is: PCIe Board with RTL8812AE don't work properly, maybe missing some firmware rtl8812aefw.bin and rtl8812aefw_wowlan.bin ...
How to copy both files to /lib/firmware/rtlwifi ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Type in terminal:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Provide the result of this command and I can help.

The dafault way is to:

```
sudo mkdir /home/username/Downloads/rtl
cd /home/username/Downloads/rtl/
wget http://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/sources/linux-firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8812aefw.bin
wget http://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/sources/linux-firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8812aefw_wowlan.bin
sudo cp rtl8812aefw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi
sudo cp rtl8812aefw_wowlan.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sysadmin